# Inserting data into more than one table

Tags: sql

If i have to put data in more than one tables at a time ,is it indicate a bad database design?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.

In one transaction you may want to add a new employee to your company, and also add his manager's name in another table.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's pretty normal in normalized database. The final result (regardless of the source of your queries - direct vs. ORM generated) should look like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO Table ...
INSERT INTO OtherTable ...

COMMIT
```

Depending on the SQL flavor, you should also consider error handling. E.g. for SQL SERVER, you can use `BEGIN TRY` ... `BEGIN CATCH` and `ROLLBACK` the transaction on error.

Comment: Thanks.everyone I thought I am a bad db designer :)